# TeXLive 2022 tries to use /root/.texlive2022 directory for an ordinary user

Tags: texlive, filesystem-access

I installed TeXLive 2022 on Linux Slackware 15.0 PC. The installation was done as root. Then I added a script `texlive.sh` to /etc/profile dir:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/info
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

So every user in the system could use TeXLive.
But when I login as an ordinary user and try to compile a file I get an error:

```
~$ xelatex ./code.tex 
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /root/.texlive2022/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt: mkdir(/root/.texlive2022/) 
failed for tree /root/.texlive2022/texmf-var/web2c:
Permission denied at /usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1178.
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
```

For some reason it tries to use `/root/.texlive2022` directory and fails. How to fix this?

Comment: what do you get reported by `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` ?

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux`   that puts the 2022 tex at the end of your path so it will not be used if you have an existing installation, eg a system tex in `/bin`. Better to put texlive at the start of the path

Comment: this could be the issue reported here https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2022-June/048225.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` --> `/root/texmf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I set the TeXLive path before $PATH, no luck.

Comment: yes that probably unrelated (but you should do it anyway) a couple of people have reported this in the thread I linked to so it'll probably get fixed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it possible to do anything myself? I need to compile Latex on this server soon?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried `$export TEXMFHOME=$HOME/texmf`. Then `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` gave the dir of my user. But it still doesn't compile the file.

Comment: As far as I can see the issue is reported but no fix posted, if you can reproduce it perhaps post there and Karl and Norbert will be able to see better with a real example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can only say, I have a fresh Slackware 15.0 installation. I installed TeXLive as root using instructions here: https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html. Then I tried to compile a file as an ordinary user and got the error.

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2022-June/048237.html Karl says it should be fixed now